# How do I make this Access sql statement work with Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

I have almost finished replacing our applications back end with Sql Server but am coming up against an issue. The following Access query is not working with Sql Server.

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN (table2
                   INNER JOIN table3
                           ON ( table2.custkey = table3.custkey )
                              AND ( table2.sequence = table3.sequence ))
               ON table1.account = table2.account
WHERE  (( LEFT(table2.keyid, 1) = 'B' ))
ORDER  BY table3.lastname & table3.firstname,
          table1.account;
```

I have tried multiple variations of this statement but have not been able to get it to work. Some help with this statement will help me modify a few others.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One other comment. On your ORDER BY, you're sorting on a derived field (i.e. lastname + firstname). This will make the db engine first combine the 2 fields, and sort the non-indexed result. 
You could instead do a ORDER  BY table3.lastname, table3.firstname,
table1.account
This will give you the same result, but faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that sticks out is "`&`" which is `+` in SQL Server.  However, `&` in access also treats NULL values as the empty string, which needs further processing with `ISNULL` in SQL Server:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN (table2
                   INNER JOIN table3
                           ON ( table2.custkey = table3.custkey )
                              AND ( table2.sequence = table3.sequence ))
               ON table1.account = table2.account
WHERE  (( LEFT(table2.keyid, 1) = 'B' ))
ORDER  BY isnull(table3.lastname,'') + isnull(table3.firstname,''),
          table1.account;
```

If I were to write the query in SQL Server from scratch, I would probably do the joins serially rather than do the t2-t3 in a bracket before joining back to t1.  The test for the first character would also be expressed as LIKE (a personal preference).

```
  SELECT table1.*
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.account = table2.account
    JOIN table3 ON table2.custkey = table3.custkey AND table2.sequence = table3.sequence
   WHERE table2.keyid LIKE 'B%'
ORDER BY isnull(table3.lastname,'') + isnull(table3.firstname,''), table1.account;
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I made those changes and it works fine now. It was the "&", I have had to change that to a + quite a few times, laps of concentration on my part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM   table1
INNER JOIN table2  ON table1.account = table2.account
INNER JOIN table3  ON ( table2.custkey = table3.custkey ) 
                      AND ( table2.sequence = table3.sequence )
WHERE  LEFT(table2.keyid, 1) = 'B' 
ORDER  BY table3.lastname, table3.firstname, table1.account;
```

If you want the where clause to be suitable for an index, rewrite using LIKE:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM   table1
INNER JOIN table2  ON table1.account = table2.account
INNER JOIN table3  ON ( table2.custkey = table3.custkey ) 
                      AND ( table2.sequence = table3.sequence )
WHERE  table2.keyid LIKE 'B%' 
ORDER  BY table3.lastname, table3.firstname, table1.account;
```